# How to protect key values for AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-proguard

My android app works with `AWS S3`. I am doing this serverless architecture, which means my app includes every information necessary to access to the `AWS S3` resources including ACCESS KEY and SECRET KEY.

Obviously it would cause security issues, and `Proguard` is not such helpful for protecting data in `String` format.

It would be great if you could share your wisdom for this.  I believe that there is some general way for this problem because I must not be the only who goes with Serverless architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As m[ichael-sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) have mentioned the Cognito is the recommended authentication way for mobile apps, however, if you can't be bothered setup up Cognito and investigating how it works you can use [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) which does not require AWS credentials to be invoked. AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity assumes requested role and generates temporary credentials valid for 1h (by default).
So the only gotcha is that you need to authenticate against any OpenID Connect-compatible identity provider.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Actually the reason I tried no to go with Cognito is its UI doesn't provide enough customization.  Your solution, AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, seems to resolve my concern about UI.  Thanks a lot.  I will let you know once I finish implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS > System Manager > Parameter Store

Comment: Not here.  Accessing parameter store requires credentials.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Michael, do you have any suggestion for my problem? Serverless architecture for android is just illussion?

Comment: [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) can be used to authenticate users and obtain temporary credenentials for your app to use, while remaining serverless.